# creating context for MVEL with different variable types

Tags: java, mvel, variable-types

I am using MVEL to evaluate arithmetic and logical expressions or a combination of the two. The thing is that I do not know beforehand all the variable types, without creating a pretty complex parsing method for the expression itself (which is passed via a settings file). I know their type only when I go through my data and update the context.
For instance, consider the expression `(a && b) && (c == 10) && (d < 5)` I separate the variables from the operators and initialize my context, but I do not know which are booleans and which are integers. I have tried to initialize all variables in the context with `null` or `new Object()` but it does not work as expected. See example code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class Test {

    private static Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String expression = "(a && b) && (c == 10) && (d < 5)";

        context.put("a", new Object());
        context.put("b", new Object());
        context.put("c", new Object());
        context.put("d", new Object());

        //do some processing and get the right value, replacing it in the context with the right type

        evaluate(expression,context); //just to try to evaluate with nothing set, crashes

        context.put("a", new Boolean(true));
        evaluate(expression,context);//crashes same as above

        context.put("b", new Boolean(true));
        evaluate(expression,context); //works. the expression is not yet true but it does not crash

        context.put("c", new Integer(10));
        context.put("d", new Integer(1));
        evaluate(expression,context); //works. expression is true

}

    private static void evaluate(String expression, Map<String,Object> context){
        if((Boolean)MVEL.eval(expression, context))
            System.out.println("Hooray");
        else
            System.out.println("Boo!"); 
    }

}
```

when it crashes, I get this message: `Exception in thread "main" org.mvel2.ScriptRuntimeException: expected Boolean; but found: java.lang.Object` If I initialize with `null` it would crash saying `..but found: null` My guess is that it figures out in the *MVEL.eval()* method it should receive booleans as the first variables, but I do not find the behavior consistent.
A second example makes me even more confused. See example code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class Test {

    private static Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        context.put("a", null);
        context.put("b", null);
        context.put("c", null);

        String expression = "( a > b + 2 ) && ( c < a - 5 )";

        evaluate(expression,context); //this time it does not crash. it evaluates correctly as false

         //do some processing and get the right value, and replace it in the context

        context.put("a",new Integer(25));
        evaluate(expression,context); //crashes. error below
        context.put("b", new Integer(20));
        context.put("c", new Integer(10));

        evaluate(expression,context); //evaluates correctly to true.
}

    private static void evaluate(String expression, Map<String,Object> context){
        if((Boolean)MVEL.eval(expression, context))
            System.out.println("Hooray");
        else
            System.out.println("Boo!"); 
    }

}
```

The error message for the crash in this second example is: `Exception in thread "main" [Error: failed to subEval expression]
[Near : {... ( a > b + 2 ) && ( c < a - 5 ) ....}]
                       ^`
Isn't there a default initialization of my context variables possible? I can initialize them with `new Boolean(false)` but that can influence the expression. Do I have to use some Strict Typing or Strong Typing? BTW, I do not find any decent documentation of the classes.. any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: even i am using MVEl, and developed my own business rule engine, underlyning layer uses MVEl to evaluate expressions, i would recommend you to build your parsing logic strongly...meaning `(a + b), a and b ` should be of `number` type only, a cannot be boolean, string in this case.

Comment: Marius also you might need to maintain the mapping of operator and supported operand datatypes etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well that is what I wanted to avoid, creating a "too" complex parsing function at that level and figure out where are the variables (left or right of the operator, etc..). Already I split the operators as logic or arithmetic where possible. BTW, are there some predefined constants that hold those operators? As mentioned, I cannot find the "decent" documentation.. maybe I got lost in the links and I suppose you got more experience than I do. If not, I thought of some workarounds. I will try them and if I come up with a clean/decent solution, will post it.

Comment: yes i agree, you will not find much on internet, but i will still force you on using some parsing logic, MVEL will not evaluate as you think, if expression is invalid in terms of MVEL, it will throw an exception. Somewhere or the other you will be putting up your intelligence either after exception is thrown from MVEL or before sending expression to MVEL.

Comment: hehehe.. YOU cannot force me :] Well, I did put in place some parsing logic, because you need to anyway, but I do not want that much overhead at that level. I did not follow everything that is going on inside MVEL.eval() functions using a Java decompiler, but I figured I can inject in the context on the fly, at the moment I find out the type of data for that variable. It is not something based on some function I found in the MVEL library, but purely how you program it.. and it is going to be a bit dirty. Thank you for your suggestions though and good luck with your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can Ask MVEL to get you the input variables automatically.   Unfortunately, MVEL does not tell you what it thinks the object type is.   So, for instance:

```
Public class MvelVarTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expression = "( a > b + 2 ) && ( c < a - 5 )";
    ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
    Serializable compiledExpression = MVEL.compileExpression(expression, context);

    //Now the context will have a list of all the inputs.  Unfortunatly it does not tell you what type of Object the input is.
    for (Map.Entry<String,Class> entry : context.getInputs().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Variable name : "+entry.getKey()+", Data Type = "+entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    //Now, you can assign values to the data and run the expression.
    Map values = new HashMap();
    values.put("a",25);
    values.put("b",20);
    values.put("c",10);

    //And we can get a boolean answer
    System.out.println("Result of running formula with (a=25, b=20, c=10) = "+MVEL.executeExpression(compiledExpression,values,Boolean.class));
}
```

}

However, when you set up the HashMap with your values, you could of just put string values in, and MVEL would of "auto converted" it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid that is not a solution. You need various types of variables as the "auto conversion" is not enough for the expressions I need to evaluate.